# How to duplicate trees from sapling tree generator?

Tags: objects, modular-tree-addon

I forgot how to duplicate trees in a scene that were created in Sapling Tree generator, if I try and copy and paste they turn into a mess. Do you make it a collection first?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried linked duplication? (Alt+D rather than Shift+D)

Comment: I added a pic, it does not copy the leaves

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate the whole tree set - in Outliner expand the treeArm arrow and select all objects paranted to the armature manually

[image]